# Failed to iterate the link list in java if using this method (hard to describe the problem in title)

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

### problem:

I am working on an algorithm in Leetcode, which is merge `k` sorted lists. I wrote the codes below, and believed that it would work out. I can successfully iterate all the nodes from the `lists[]` (if I comment this line `res = insertIntoList(curr,res);`), and I can successfully insert nodes into the `res` list (if I uncomment the last three lines in the method `mergeKLists`).  However, if I just run this method with no changes, I will get the error `Time limit exceeded`, where I found out that the `curr` in the `while` loop doesn't actually change to the next node, it keep using the first node and running again and again. I tried everything and couldn't find where the problem is. Maybe you can, thanks for reading all of these.

### Description:

```
23. Merge k Sorted Lists
Merge k sorted linked lists and return it as one sorted list. Analyze and describe its complexity.

Example:

Input:   
[
  1->4->5,
  1->3->4,
  2->6
]

Lists[]: [[1,4,5],[1,3,4],[2,6]] 
Output: 1->1->2->3->4->4->5->6
```

### code:

```
public ListNode mergeKLists(ListNode[] lists) {
        if(lists == null)
            return null;
        ListNode res = lists[0];
        for(int i = 1; i < lists.length; i++) {
            ListNode curr = lists[i];
            while(curr != null) {
                System.out.println("outside curr1:\t"+curr.val);
                res = insertIntoList(curr,res);
                System.out.println("outside curr2:\t"+curr.val);
                curr = curr.next;
            }
        }
        return res;
        /**
        ListNode res = lists[0];
        ListNode test = lists[1].next.next;
        return insertIntoList(test,res);**/
    }
    
    public ListNode insertIntoList(ListNode toBeInsert, ListNode res) {
        if(toBeInsert.val <= res.val) {
            toBeInsert.next = res;
            return toBeInsert;
        }
        
        ListNode curr = res;
        while(curr != null) {
            System.out.println("inside curr:\t"+curr.val);
            
            if ((toBeInsert.val > curr.val) && (toBeInsert.val > curr.next.val))
                curr = curr.next;
            
            ListNode tmp = curr.next;
            curr.next = toBeInsert;
            toBeInsert.next = tmp;
            break;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm sounds efficient. Maybe, your bug would be here in this line:

```
toBeInsert.next = tmp;
```

change it to

```
toBeInsert = tmp;
```

I'm not sure though.

If you want, you can use Priority Queue for this problem, makes it much easier:

```
public class Solution {
    public static final ListNode mergeKLists(ListNode[] lists) {
        if (lists == null || lists.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        PriorityQueue<ListNode> queue = new PriorityQueue<ListNode>(lists.length, (a, b) -> a.val - b.val);
        ListNode dummy = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode curr = dummy;

        for (ListNode node : lists)
            if (node != null) {
                queue.add(node);
            }

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            curr.next = queue.poll();
            curr = curr.next;

            if (curr.next != null) {
                queue.add(curr.next);
            }
        }

        return dummy.next;
    }
}
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-k-sorted-lists/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.

Comment: Thanks for improving, but I really want to know where the bug is.